# Proving this piecewise function is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let, $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Leb. measurable. I wish to show that, $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   0 & ,\text{if } g(x) = 0\\
   \frac{1}{g(x)}       & ,\text{if } g(x) \ne 0
  \end{cases}$

is Leb. measurable. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose, $\alpha \le 0$. Then,

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) < \alpha\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \frac{1}{g(x)} < \alpha\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) > \frac{1}{\alpha} \}.$$
The last set in the chain of equalities is Leb. measurable because $g$ is Leb. measurable.
Hence, $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) < \alpha \}$ is Leb. measurable. Suppose, $\alpha > 0$. Then,
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) < \alpha\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) < 0\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) = 0\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < f(x) < \alpha  \}.$$
We wish to show that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < f(x) < \alpha \}$ is  Leb. measurable.
We have that,
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < f(x) < \alpha  \}  = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < \frac{1}{g(x)} < \alpha \} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) > \alpha  \}.$$

The last set in the chain of equalities is Leb. measurable because $g$ is Leb. measurable. It is also obvious that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) = 0\}$ is Leb. measurable because $\{0\}$ is Leb. measurable. Hence, $f$ is Leb. measurable.

Any problems with this proof? Thanks.

Comment: Did you want to say anything about $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) < 0\}\;$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no disastrous problems with this proof, it looks good. I advocate one change, however. I would handle the case $\alpha=0$ separately:

Suppose, $\alpha = 0$. Then

$$\{x: f(x) < 0\}  =  \{x: f(x) < 0,\, g(x)\not=0\}  =  \{x: \frac{1}{g(x)} < 0\}=  \{x:  g(x) < 0\}.$$

The way you have it now, we get a division by zero:

Suppose, $\alpha \le 0$. Then,

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) < 0\} = \{x: \frac{1}{g(x)} < 0\} = \{x: g(x) > \frac{1}{0} \}.$$

In fact, even writing $1/0 = \infty$, I think this last step is no good.